# Mark up and style in accordance with a design task

Tags: html, css

I'm studying MOOC in HTML, CSS and Javascript. And did weekly assignment task which was reviewed by 5 random course learners (I reviewed 5 other student's assignments as well). Unfortunately, I received like mere 3-5 words-long reviews, though all are positive.

Could anybody, please have a look at my code and point out any issues or inconsistencies to the best practices?

Design to implement:
[image: design to implement]

[My implementation (hosted on AWS)](http://code-review.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com)

Code of my implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online dating</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        fieldset {
            background: lightyellow;
            border: 10px solid yellow;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            width: 720px;
        }
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 180px;
            vertical-align: top;
            text-align: right;
        }
        textarea {
            width: 360px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .labelOfRadioOrCheckbox {
            width: auto;
        }
        .sliderLabel {
            color: white;
            width: 4em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .darkRedBackground {
            background: #A72B26;
        }
        .purpleBackground {
            background: #832F82;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Please Enter Your Details For Our Dating Website!</h1>

<form action="https://ihome.ust.hk/~rossiter/cgi-bin/show_everything.php"
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Face</legend>

        <label for="avatarUpload">Your image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatarUpload" required>
        <br>
        <label for="preview">Image preview:</label>
        <img id="preview" alt=""> <!-- will be handled with inline JS-script,
                                    src and alt attributes are omitted intently -->
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your General Details</legend>

        <label for="nameField">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="nameField" placeholder="Your full name" required>
        <br>
        <label for="maleRadio">Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="maleRadio">Male
        <label for="femaleRadio" class="labelOfRadioOrCheckbox"></label> <!-- dummy label to avoid
            radio button without label error in w3c validator-->
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="femaleRadio">Female
        <br>
        <label for="ageField">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" value="18" id="ageField" required>
        <br>
        <label for="dateOfBirthField">Date of birth:</label>
        <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirthField">
        <br>
        <label for="favoriteColorPicker">Favorite color:</label>
        <input type="color" name="favoriteColor" id="favoriteColorPicker">
        <br>
        <label for="countrySelect">Which country:</label>
        <select name="country" id="countrySelect">
            <option>Select</option> <!-- dummy option to handle 'no selection' -->
            <option value="ru">Russia</option>
            <option value="us">United States</option>
            <option value="it">Italy</option>
            <option value="fr">France</option>
            <option value="au">Australia</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Indicators</legend>

        <label for="heightSlider">Height:</label>
        <label for="heightSlider" class="sliderLabel darkRedBackground">Short</label>
        <input type="range" name="height" id="heightSlider" max="100" value="50">
        <label for="heightSlider" class="sliderLabel purpleBackground">Tall</label>
        <br>
        <label for="salarySlider">Salary:</label>
        <label for="salarySlider" class="sliderLabel darkRedBackground">Poor</label>
        <input type="range" name="height" id="salarySlider" max="100" value="50">
        <label for="salarySlider" class="sliderLabel purpleBackground">Rich</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Contact Information</legend>
        <label for="emailField">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="emailField">
        <br>
        <label for="mobileField">Mobile:</label>
        <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobileField">
        <br>
        <label for="addressField">Address:</label>
        <textarea name="address" id="addressField" ></textarea>
        <br>
        <label for="emailContactMethodCheckbox">Method to contact you:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod" id="emailContactMethodCheckbox" value="email">
        Email
        <label for="whatsappContactMethodCheckbox" class="labelOfRadioOrCheckbox"></label> <!-- dummy label to avoid
            radio button without label error in w3c validator-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod" id="whatsappContactMethodCheckbox" value="whatsapp">
        Whatsapp
        <label for="inAppChatContactMethodCheckbox" class="labelOfRadioOrCheckbox"></label> <!-- dummy label to avoid
            radio button without label error in w3c validator-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod" id="inAppChatContactMethodCheckbox" value="inAppChat">
        In-app chat
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Don't use `<br>`s as a design element (i.e. breaking lines for a layout). Use CSS's `display: block` or surround with `<div>` or `<p>` elements. `<br>`s are meant for line breaks in text, without breaking the context of a paragraph.
- The `for=` attribute on `<label>` elements only works for input elements like `<input>`, `<button>` and `<textarea>`, it does not work for `<img>`. Also, the `<img>` element must have a `src=` attribute according to the specs.
- If the label and the input are close, you don't really need to dirty your ID space with unneeded IDs. You can use the following pattern:

  ```
  <label>Email: <input ... /></label>
  ```

  This also allows you to use the very handy trick of `label { display: block; }` to instantly break lines easily.

---

Design-wise:

- Try to use more subtle colors, colors with lower contrast and lower hue and brightness value. Black on yellow is what they reserve for WARNING! signs. (I realize that the design is a given by your professor/teacher, that doesn't mean you can't improve on it and make it look better)
- Try not constraining yourself to a single, set, width. Today, more people tend to surf the web through a mobile device with lower resolutions. Make sure your site looks good for those people.
- Avoid class names like `darkBackground` and `purpleBackground`, classes are *not* design tools. They are *semantic* tools that happen to be useful with design. Class names like `lowerBound` and `higherBound` sound a whole lot better, it also instantly tells the reader what these elements are.

Comment: Thanks for good advice. Actually, I picked up using IDs for labels and separating them with `<br>`  from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) and thought it was a kind of best practice. But I agree that it bloats code and also <br> is used in not-semantic way.

Comment: w3school is a horrible site that should be taken down from the internet. Please use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) from this point.